# bootstrap gutter width and grid centering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for ways to center a container in bootstrap and reduce gutter width but haven't been able to find a solution. I have a grid of images (2 rows, 3 columns) and I want to be able to reduce the width of the gutters between columns and add a horizontal gutter between the two rows. I would like to be able to center the grid.

```
<body>
<div class="container" width="400px" >
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail"     src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg"/ width= '100px'>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img  width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img  width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img  width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" />     
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img  width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img  width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried writing custom code? Bootstrap is a framework, build upon it

Comment: Setting image width 100px cancels out using `img-responsive`

Comment: You're also using two class tags and what is the point of using `img-responsive` if you're using a fixed width of 100px? `width= '100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail"`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making a simple class to use where you need row padding.

```
.row-padded 
{
    margin-top:20px; 
}
```

Same for removing spacing between columns.

```
.column-nospace
{
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

There will likely be times when you need Bootstrap to function as intended out of the box, so I recommend these over editing the core Bootstrap files.

Here is a fiddle that shows what you want (I think).  https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/583/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has an offset that can be defined for each col.

You can wrap each row in a col-md-6 and give it an offset of 3.

Bootstrap does their grid with width percentages. So if your column is 6 wide, it will be 50% wide and a margin of 25% on each side will center the column.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail"
                 src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg" width='100px'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img width='100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail"
                 src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img width='100px' class='img-responsive' class="thumbnail"
                 src="http://www.hutterites.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/placeholder.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```